# Is there a way to get total AWS S3 bucket PUT costs using boto3?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I am trying to calculate the costs of a S3 bucket using boto3.
For the size, I am using list_objects(bucketname)['contents'].

Is there a way I can get the total PUT costs or total PUT requests for the bucket?
Any API's that support this?

Thanks

Comment: I haven't tried it, but you might be able to use: [CostExplorer — Boto 3 Docs documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ce.html#CostExplorer.Client.get_cost_and_usage)

Answer (score 1):

You should be using cloudwatch metrics for identifying put requests. for details refer [cloudwatch for S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cloudwatch-monitoring.html)

`aws cloudwatch list-metrics --namespace "AWS/S3"`